# Explain LINQ All() expression

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if any one can help explain this expression with two lists,

```
originalForm.FormItems.Where(x =>
     newForm.FormItems.All(y => y.ItemId != x.ItemId));
```

I think it is supposed to return items that are in originalForm but not in newForm, however, when I try and understand it myself I think it's saying the opposite. If someone could break it down for me, it'd be a big help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are far easier ways to do this, eg use `.Except()` between the list of ItemIDs, or put all `ItemIds` into HashSets and find the difference

Comment: Perhaps try thinking of `newForm.FormItems.All( IsNotEqual )` like the equivalent pseudo-code `newForm.FormItems.None( IsEqual )` to untie your mental knot...

Comment: `All` returns true if all the elements in the sequence satisfy the given predicate (condition). So here we are selecing from the originalForm items where the newForm itemIds does not match any itemId in originalForm. Not surprised you are confused! I'd use Contains on the inner predicate or Except (see below)

Answer (score 6):

An equivalent of your code that is a little more clear is this code using `Except`:

```
var l = originalForm.Select(x => x.ItemId).Except(newForm.FormItems.Select(y => y.ItemId));
```

This will only get you the item IDs. You can look the actual items back later on if you need them:

```
originalForm.Where(x => l.Contains(x.ItemId));
```

Your code "where not any" is "where none", which is the same as "except".

Comment: I think it should be `originalForm.Where(x => !newForm.Select(x => x.ItemId).Contains(x.ItemId));`, since the OP is looking for items in the originalForm that's not in the newForm. Anyway, `Contains` is much more sensible then `All` or my alternative with `Any`. +1.

Comment: That is the purpose of `Except`, right? (A-B) @ZoharPeled

Comment: @ZoharPeled I saw your answer too, not sure why it was downvoted as it seems a decent alternative.

Comment: The funny thing is that is was downvoted literally the second I posted it. I didn't even get the chance of loading your answer when mine already got the -1. I was actually going to edit it to include the `contains` option as well (didn't think `Except` is going to do much good since the condition is on a single property), but then I saw your answer so I figured what the hell, I'll just delete mine.

Comment: You might want to consider undeleting.

Comment: This is not an answer to what was asked. This just proves an alternate solution to the problem which raised OP's question!

Comment: Why not? @Mardoxx

Comment: @Mardoxx on the contrary, this *does* answer the question by providing clearer equivalent code. The OP asked for the difference between sets using the wrong wording. The difference between sets is implemented by Except in LINQ and SQL. `ALL` and `ANY` are ways to implement set difference *without* using the set difference operation. Databases like SQL Server recognize this and often simplify such code to the same execution plan

Comment: @PatrickHofman because it doesn't teach anything other than "to get the difference of the sets use this method", it doesn't explain why what OP wrote works when they think it shouldnt. Hopefully it gives the intuition to arrive at a better understanding though!!

Comment: Well, I took your advice (and Mardoxx's as well)

Comment: @Mardoxx Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, that is what it does, and it is a strange implementation.
I would use `Any` instead of `All`:

```
originalForm.FormItems.Where(x =>
 !newForm.FormItems.Any(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId));
```

I think it's much more readable.

The `All` method will return `true` if all of the elements in the `IEnumerable` returns true for the given predicate.

Taken from [the source code of Enumerable.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), here is how it's implemented.

```
    public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            if (!predicate(element)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

So basically, it will return `true` only if all the elements of the `newForm.FormItems` have an `ItemId` property that is different then the current element from `originalForm.FormItems` being tested currently in the `Where`.

The `Any` method is the exact opposite - it will return `true` if at least one of the elements in the `IEnumerable` returns `true`.

There is another option which is even simpler - and that's to use `Contains`:

```
originalForm.FormItems.Where(x => !newForm.FormItems.Contains(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negation of the `Any` expression while checking for equality. Like that it might not always check all the items of the second collection.

```
originalForm.FormItems.Where(x =>
 !newForm.FormItems.Any(y => y.ItemId == x.ItemId));
```

`Any` will return as soon as it find 1 item that match the expression. So this create 2 scenarios.

Scenario 1 : If the original id exist in the second list the `Any` will find the first occurrence and return `true`, Then it get negated to `false` and so it doesn't pick the item in the return results.

Scenario 2 : If the original id does not exist in the second list the `Any` will test all the items of the second list and wont find any so it will return `false`, Then it get negated to `true` and so the item is in the return results.

Answer (score -2):

The set operation you are looking for is subtraction, which is implemented by LINQ's Except method. You want the form items in Form 1 *minus* the items in form 2 based on their IDs.

In SQL you'd use the `NOT IN (...)` clause to achieve the same

When you don't have an explicit subtraction operator, you cam implement subtraction by including *ALL* items that don't match a mismatch condition (like your code), or excluding *ANY* that match an equality condition.

The most common version of [Enumerable.Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) compares objects using their equality operators. You can use this to find the unique ItemIDs and then retrieve the form items.

Another overload allows you to specify a comparer. Unfortunately there's no built-in way to specify a comparison predicate, so you have to create a custom comparer class that inherits from eg [EqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx) and compares only the ItemId properties.

A better option is to use the [ExceptBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs) that allows you to specify the key used for comparison, eg :

```
var uniqueItems=originalForm.FormItems
                            .ExceptBy(newForm.FormItems,it=>it.ItemId);
```

You can add MoreLINQ as a binary [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) or you can add the code to your project by adding the [MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ExceptBy source package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ExceptBy/)